# Add data attribute to google analytics tag added by google tag manager

Tags: gtag.js, cookieconsent

I use google tag manager to add ga script to my page. I am using Cookie consent plugin https://github.com/orestbida/cookieconsent. To control scripts it is recommended to add data-cookiecategory="analytics" attribute to script link. Is this possible to do in google tag manager? There are no options to add any attribute. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @user1031743 - I've just started using this same library. How did you get on? I have a couple questions about the setup